# Share variable between instances of the same class in python

Tags: python, class

I have a class that I need:

1. First instance MUST receive a parameter.
2. All the following instances have this parameter be optional.

If it is not passed then I will use the parameter of the previous object init.

For that, I need to share a variable between the objects (all objects belong to classes with the same parent).

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    shared_variable = None

    def __init__(self, paremeter_optional=None):
        if paremeter_optional is None:      # Parameter optional not given
            if self.shared_variable is None:
                print("Error! First intance must have the parameter")
                sys.exit(-1)
            else:
                paremeter_optional = self.shared_variable       # Use last parameter

        self.shared_variable = paremeter_optional        # Save it for next object

objA = MyClass(3)
objB = MyClass()
```

Because the shared_variable is not consistent/shared across inits, when running the above code I get the error:

```
Error! First intance must have the parameter
```

(After the second init of objB)

Of course, I could use a global variable but I want to avoid it if possible and use some best practices for this.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please specify what problems did you encounter with your example

Comment: So can instances after the first override the shared variable for every instance after that?

Comment: @AminGuermazi actually, if you just copy-paste that code you will have the error message when creating object B.

Comment: @AlexHall Good question, sorry. The optional parameter is just used in the constructor and gets lost, same for the shared_variable, they are not important, just used once in the constructor.

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina still, it is expected to post the actual problem/error you get...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ok, changed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a value to `self.shared_variable` makes `self.shared_variable` an instance attribute so that the value is not shared among instances.

You can instead assign the value explicitly to the class attribute by referencing the attribute of the instance's class object instead.

Change:

```
self.shared_variable = paremeter_optional
```

to:

```
self.__class__.shared_variable = paremeter_optional
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Worked. I have to wait 7 min and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Explicitly naming `MyClass` may be more appropriate than using `self.__class__`, depending on what behavior is expected for subclasses. Will they have their own class variables, or should the root class's variable be used everywhere? Different designs may prefer different answers to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Having misunderstood the original problem, I would still recommend being explicit, rather than having the class track information better tracked *outside* the class.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        ...

objA = MyClass(3)
objB = MyClass(4)
objC = MyClass(5)
objD = MyClass(5)  # Be explicit; don't "remember" what was used for objC
```

If `objC` and `objD` are "related" enough that `objD` can rely on the initialization of `objC`, and you want to be DRY, use something like

```
objC, objD = [MyClass(5) for _ in range(2)]
```

---

Original answer:

I wouldn't make this something you set from an instance at all; it's a class attribute, and so should be set at the class level only.

```
class MyClass:
    shared_variable = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.shared_variable is None:
            raise RuntimeError("shared_variable must be set before instantiating")

        ...


MyClass.shared_variable = 3
objA = MyClass()
objB = MyClass()
```

Comment: For my case, as I want the first parameter to have it optional the actual code will be: `objA = MyClass(3)
MyClass.shared_variable = 3
objB = MyClass() `
And every time I actually give the constructor the parameter then I will have to change the class parameter which will be ugly in my opinion.

Comment: That's what the direct assignment to `MyClass.shared_variable` does; it sets the value once for *all* objects, regardless of which object is created first. *No* object sets the value as part of its initialization; you don't have it be a parameter for `__init__` at all.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I want it to be possible to do:
`objA = MyClass(3)
objB = MyClass(4)
objC = MyClass(5)
objD = MyClass()`
objD here must have 5, and C should have used 4 if the parameter was not passed and so on. In your case I would have to personally assign it each time, I am not saying is not a solution, that's why I upvoted it. Just that I believe is not so nice for my application in particular.

Comment: I really don't recommend complicating the class for this. What is the benefit to not having to require an explicit value when you instantiate `objD`?

Comment: I want a mode of working similar to Keras sequential layers, in there, the first layer must be given an input size, and the next ones can (or not) be given the input size, if not, will use last layers size and add it just after the previous.